# Server socket with swift

Tags: ios, sockets, swift

I want to be able to have one ios-device that multiple ios-devices (is there any max?) are able to connect to and send data(a string in this case) to the first device.

I have tried this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/networking-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server
But I have a hard time understanding Objective-C

Comment: I am also on your way. I have succeded in sending messages to a server and could display those messages in Terminal. What is your status?

Comment: @Jess The same I think. I managed to send a string to a server, and the server send a string to any connected device! You can checkout my GitHub repository where I'm using it http://github.com/Totoajax/Alfons

Comment: I checked your git project. .xcodeproj file is missing.

Comment: @Jess I've uploaded it now :)

Comment: Good work done. I did the same using NSStream and swift.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, for swift it will be the same as for objC. All you need is to port syntax from objC to swift:

```
func initNetworkCommunication() {
    var readStream : Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?;
    var writeStream : Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil, "localhost", 80, &readStream, &writeStream);
    if let read = readStream {
        inputStream = readStream!.takeUnretainedValue()
    }
    if let write = writeStream {
       outputStream = writeStream!.takeUnretainedValue()
    }
}
```

and so on...